# Eclipse C: Error Starting Process - Launching Failed Cannot Run Program

Tags: c, eclipse, runtime-error, mingw

I've been trying to setup Eclipse for some C developing. I manage to get the example "hello world" program (provided by Eclipse) to compile, however I am unable to run or debug it. Since I am able to compile, I assume that the setup for the compiler is correct, I can also find the executable file in the workspace (which will not run manually).

While trying to run it through Eclipse I get the error "Error Starting Process - Launching Failed, Cannot run program".

While trying to debug it from Eclipse, I get the error "Error in final launch sequence: Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run" and "Error creating process %path to executable%(error 5)".

I've tried changing workspace to one that has no spaces and to reinstall the compiler (MinGW) with no success.

If anyone could provide some insight on the problem I'd be very grateful.

Edit: Attempting to run the executable returns the following error: "Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." This is strange as I am running it as an admin on my machine.

Furthermore, attempting to run the executable from an administrator permission level command prompt window returns "access is denied".

Comment: So you are saying, that all 3 methods you try are failing: 1) running the executable manually (from the command line?), 2) running the executable from Eclipse, and 3) debugging the executable from Eclipse?

Comment: that is correct, I've tried all three and all of them fail

Comment: Then I'd say Eclipse is giving you the right error message. The executable can't be launched. Which error does the manual try produce?

Comment: I've tried running the file outside of Eclipse in a number of ways. It seems to be a permission issue, I am confused as to why since I am running this as an admin on my machine

Comment: My proposal is to compile and link that simple "hello world" on the command line to make sure that your compiler tool chain is working. As long as you can't do this manually, Eclipse can't do it either.

Comment: Calling the gcc function outputs an executable without raising any error, I am still unable to run the executable however (same errors as previously stated). I've tried moving the file to another directory where I know I have admin rights, but get the same result.

Comment: So I'm out, this looks like Windows' problem, and I don't want to spend time in that.

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue: it turns out my anti-virus software was preventing the file from executing without notifying me. Thank you for your help @thebusybee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my anti-virus software was blocking the file's execution, disabled it and the program ran just fine.